# Position: absolute not working in relative to another div

Tags: html, css, sass

I have the following `html` code:

```
<div class="dealItemOptionsStoreaddressContainer">
    <button class="dealItemOptionsStoreAddress dealItemStoreAddress" type="button" data-dealid=<?php echo $dealItem['id']; ?>>
        <svg class="dealItemOptionsStoreAddress__svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
            <path d="M256,0C153.755,0,70.573,83.182,70.573,185.426c0,126.888,165.939,313.167,173.004,321.035
            c6.636,7.391,18.222,7.378,24.846,0c7.065-7.868,173.004-194.147,173.004-321.035C441.425,83.182,358.244,0,256,0z M256,278.719
            c-51.442,0-93.292-41.851-93.292-93.293S204.559,92.134,256,92.134s93.291,41.851,93.291,93.293S307.441,278.719,256,278.719z"/>
        </svg>
        <span class="dealItemOptionsStoreAddress__text"><?php echo $dealItem['store_address']; ?></span>
    </button>
    <div class="dealItemOptionsStoreaddressContainer__map"></div>
</div>
```

And this is the `SCSS` (css) code:

```
.dealItemOptionsStoreaddressContainer {
    grid-column: 5 / span 1;
    grid-row: 5 / span 1;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    position: relative;

    &__map {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 25px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 150px;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 8px -5px black;
        border: 7px solid map-get($webColors, 'button-red');
    }
}

.dealItemOptionsStoreAddress {
    background-color: map-get($webColors, 'button-red');
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 7px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow-x: hidden;

    &:hover {
        background-color: map-get($webColors, 'light-button-red');
    }

    &__svg {
        fill: white;
        height: calc(12px + 0.2vw);
        min-width: calc(12px + 0.2vw);
        margin-left: 5px;
    }

    &__text {
        color: white;
        font-size: calc(10px + 0.3vw);
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
}
```

I did `position: absolute` to `<div class="dealItemOptionsStoreaddressContainer__map"></div>` and `position: relative` to `<div class="dealItemOptionsStoreaddressContainer">` but It just like not working in the way it supposed to be.. The browser shows these `div`s as there is no `position` at all to neither the inner div nor the outer div.

[image]

[image]

In the pictures you can see the browser puts the inner div just below, instead of using the `position: absolute`.

However, I'd expect to see:
[image]

Comment: sass and css are not the same thing, any more than javascript is the same as assembly  even though it eventually gets turned into assembly.  Your question doesn't include CSS and thus shouldn't include the label.

Comment: to me, it seems working, maybe the issue is with: top:25px; while the button could be 30px of height, both can then be overlapping. what is it supposed to be alike ? (your screenshot are not telling me much :)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I added an expected result image.

Comment: okay, remove overflow-x:hidden, then the "map" will be shown below it, and not inside it

Comment: @G-Cyrillus This property is necessary for me for other html aspect.. Why is that happening? I need to keep this property